# I am getting error in date format in oracle

Tags: oracle

I want the date format in yyyy-mm-dd but I am getting error

Here is the code

table creation

```
create table orders
  2  (ord_no int,
  3   purch_amt float,
  4  ord_date date,
  5  customer_id int,
  6  salesman_id int);
```

insertion in the table

```
insert all
  2  into orders(ord_no,purch_amt,ord_date,customer_id,salesman_id)values(70001,150.5,'2012-10-05',3005,5002)
  3  into orders(ord_no,purch_amt,ord_date,customer_id,salesman_id)values(70009,270.65,'2012-09-10',3001,5005)
  4  into orders(ord_no,purch_amt,ord_date,customer_id,salesman_id)values(70002,65.26,'2012-10-05',3002,5001)
  5  into orders(ord_no,purch_amt,ord_date,customer_id,salesman_id)values(70004,110.5,'2012-08-17',3009,5003)
  6  into orders(ord_no,purch_amt,ord_date,customer_id,salesman_id)values(70007,948.5,'2012-09-10',3005,5002)
  7  into orders(ord_no,purch_amt,ord_date,customer_id,salesman_id)values(70005,2400.6,'2012-07-27',3007,5001)
  8  into orders(ord_no,purch_amt,ord_date,customer_id,salesman_id)values(70008,5760,'2012-09-10',3002,5001)
  9  select * from dual;
into orders(ord_no,purch_amt,ord_date,customer_id,salesman_id)values(70001,150.5,'2012-10-05',3005,5002)
```

I am getting this error

```
into orders(ord_no,purch_amt,ord_date,customer_id,salesman_id)values(70001,150.5,'2012-10-05',3005,5002)
                                                                                 *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

Answer (score 1):

`'2012-10-05'` is a **string**, not a `DATE`. Either

- use `DATE` literal: `DATE '2012-10-05'`
- explicit format specifier `TO_DATE('2012-10-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD')`
- set default date format `alter session NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD';`

Answer (score 0):

Unless that is the default date format for the database or the default for the session (set via [NLS_DATE_FORMAT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/NLS_DATE_FORMAT.html#GUID-FC23EEEE-AA9F-4B3C-8CBB-888C9C0CA27F), it won't work. I prefer to use the TO_DATE() function and specify the format and not rely on the default.